# Linksys wrt3200acm - connection issue

Tags: wireless-networking, router

I own a 'refurbished' Linksys wrt3200acm. I loved it. Owned it for a year. 2.4 GHz was fine and on 5GHz my laptop would give me speeds comparable to a wired connection. A few days ago I preloaded BFV remotely from my android. I expected my ISP to throttle me. But, they did not. I downloaded 40 -50 GB in 30 minutes at a rate of 200Mb (20MB). I am only supposed to be 150Mb (15MB). I performed the preload during the day.

When I got home, I learned that we have been having disconnect issues and slow WiFi. I tested the system for a few hours. All wirelesssly connected devices was slow on both frequesncies. I rest the router. I do not need to 30 30 30 reset because the router model is new enough. I attempted to roll back the router, but the router did not roll back. The linksys website did not provide a link to previous firmware  updates. I turned off several things such as QOS, WIFI protected set up, changed the MTU 20 1497.

And then the strangest of strangest things happened. Last year I attempted to create a wifi bridge with my older and discontinued Netgear R7500 (AC2350). I thought I failed. I attempted to set it up again, but I didn't have to. As soon as I hooked it up to my laptop (laptop wifi was turned off) I had an internet connection. Surprise. Here's the thing. I am getting 150Mb on the wifi bridge.

Why is the primary router giving poor wireless quality to all devices except to the secondary router?

Comment: Problem with the router? Try to reset it.

Comment: Don't turn off wireless QoS (WMM). It is required by 802.11n and later. You can't get the fastest Wi-Fi speeds without it.

Comment: Ok. I turned it on. I have to turn on Media Prioritization to activate it. But I am not prioritizing any devices. I am getting 90Mb instead of 150Mb at 31 ms. Game lag and disconnections still happening. It used to run at 150 Mb at 31 ms, no lag and no disconnects. Wired is fine.